# Find integer solution of $\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{y} = \frac{1}{2020}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find all pairs of integers $(x,y)$ for

$$\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{y} = \frac{1}{2020}$$

---

Attempt:

Notice $x,y \ne 0$.

$$ \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{y} = \frac{1}{2020} $$

$$ \frac{x+y}{xy} = \frac{1}{2020} $$

$$ 2020(x+y) = xy $$

$$2020x + 2020y = xy$$

$$x(2020-y) = -2020y $$

$$x = \frac{2020y}{y-2020}$$

Notice $2020 = 101(5)2^{2}$, so the divisors are $1,2,4,5,10,20,101,202,404,505,1010,2020$.

If we check where $y-2020 | 2020$, then the solutions for $y$ are:
$$y = 2020+1, 2020+2, 2020+4, 2020+5, 2020+10, 2020+20, ..., 2020+2020$$
along with the corresponding $x$.

If we check $y-2020 | y$, then notice that $\frac{y}{y-2020} = 1 + \frac{2020}{y-2020}$, so it will be integer only if $\frac{2020}{y-2020}$ is integer, which means the $y$ solution is the same as before.

So far I have only found $12$ solutions.

Comment: p|ab need not mean that p has to divide at least one of a or b. Eg. 4 divides neither 18 nor 10, but divides their product 180.

Comment: **Hint :** $$2020(x+y) = xy \Longleftrightarrow (x-2020)(y-2020)=2020^2$$

Comment: The same "completing the product" method in the dupe applies here (e.g. prior comment).